# How do I perform a Bulk Write operation using the MongoDB Atlas Data API?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am using the MongoDB Data API on Atlas from a serverless function, and I’m attempting to update many documents (thousands) with different values for each. Reading through the Data API documentation it seems as though there is no `/bulk` or `/bulkWrite` action available.

In this case I have the document _id’s of each document I’d like to update and their respective changes. I attempted to add them all to a bulk update array like so:

```
const userIds = ['123', 'abc', '567', ...];
let bulkArr = [];

for (const id of userIds) {
  bulkArr.push({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { _id: { $oid: id} },
      update: { $addToSet: { someArray: 'some value' } },
    },
  });
}
```

Then I tried making a request like this:

```
var requestData = JSON.stringify({
  collection: "<collection>",
  database: "<database>",
  dataSource: "<datasource>",
  operations: bulkArr,
});

var config = {
  method: "post",
  url: "https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-somekey/endpoint/data/v1/action/bulkWrite",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
    "api-key": "<api_key>",
  },
  data: requestData,
};

await axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error({
      status: error.response.status,
      message: "Update failed: " + error.response.statusText,
    });
    return error;
  });
```

This returns a 404. How can I perform a bulk update operation that is similar to this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Not sure if this a full-blown solution (and ideally there would be a built-in /bulkWrite endpoint...), but perhaps a custom endpoint would work? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/data-api/custom-endpoints/